# Разница между "сильный", "острый" и "резкий" (запах)

Tags: выбор-слова, прилагательные, словоупотребление

Тему прилагательных описывающих запахи и звуки в русском языке можно обсуждать бесконечно. Я сужу вопрос до трёх прилагательных:

- Сильный (запах)
- Острый (запах)
- Резкий (запах)

Одно ли это и тоже, или есть различия? Скажем, может запах быть острым, но не сильным? Или сильным но не острым? Также мы можем рассмотреть другие возможные пары (острый - резкий) и  (резкий - сильный).

Словари русского языка в этом вопросе помогают слабо. Например, у Ожегова мы находим под заголовком "острый": "5. Сильно действующий на вкус или обоняние". Искать там слово "сильный" - просто бесполезно. Оно там есть, но категория запаха отдельно не выделена. Похожая ситуация и с другими словарями.

С лингвистической точки зрения, слова описывающие запахи и звуки заметно различаются в разных языках и вызывают трудности при переводе. И тем не менее, давайте разберёмся в этом частном случае: три слова, один язык.

Answer (score 8):

Сильный запах - количественная характеристика, запах, отличающийся силой, амплитудой. Причем, относительно среднего, нормального, ожидаемого уровня того же запаха. Например, "в квартире стоял сильный запах газа". При этом сам запах мог быть едва уловимым, но поскольку запах газа в квартире вообще не ожидается, его можно назвать "сильным", так как запах газа свидетельствует о его большой концентрации. При этом подчеркивается именно уровень запаха, а не его качественные особенности. Сильный запах может быть приятным.

Резкий запах - качественная характеристика. Запах, отличающийся от других запахов, привлекающий внимание, выделяющийся, часто неприятный. Например, у фекалий, у чеснока резкий запах, всегда. Можно сказать "у моей кошки резкий запах".

Острый запах - я бы сказал, то же самое, что и резкий, но связанный с опасностью, настораживающий. Например, нельзя сказать, что у кошки острый запах. А вот острый запах гари вполне может быть.

Comment: Амплитуда запаха? :)

Answer (score 3):

Перефразируя известное высказывание Фрэнка Заппы о разговорах про музыку, можно сказать, что и говорить о запахах — это всё равно что танцевать об архитектуре. Запахи называются по объекту или веществу их издающему, а все прилагательные, описывающие запахи, являются сугубо субъективными, один и тот же запах может одному человеку казаться родным и вызывающим тёплые воспоминания о детстве, другому же он может казаться неприятным и настораживающим.

Насчёт сильного запаха я согласен с [Anixx](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/194/anixx), но вот что резкий запах часто неприятный, с этим можно поспорить, не говоря уже о том, что кошки вообще-то не пахнут.

> Из лесу струёй бил **резкий запах** тающего снега, прелых листьев. [Юрий Коваль. Лесник Булыга (1985)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E5%E7%EA%E8%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&docid=84598)
>
> Нет, это какой-то особый, более **резкий запах**, но он настолько приятный и раздражающий, что возле булочной слюна наполняет рот. [Полина Барскова. Черный свет: проблема темноты в блокадном Ленинграде // «Неприкосновенный запас», 2010](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E5%E7%EA%E8%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&docid=45210)
>
> Ночью **резкий запах моря** добивал далеко вглубь земли, утром я нырял в маске, летал над песочными полями… [Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E5%E7%EA%E8%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&docid=20985)
>
> Странный **резкий запах** идет от него ― смолистый, густой, веселый, ошеломительный запах-дурман. [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F0%E5%E7%EA%E8%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&p=1&docid=20743)

Резкий – это такой, который режет, вызывает сильные чувства, а уж какими эти чувства могут быть, тут всё зависит от того, кто этот запах воспринимает (слышит? чует?).

Острый запах не обязательно связан с опасностью, не всегда настораживающий.

> В доме поселился непривычный **острый запах младенца**. [Михаил Шишкин. Всех ожидает одна ночь (1993-2003)](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CE%F1%F2%F0%FB%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&p=1&docid=20822)
>
> Или: «Иду лесом к речке ― **острый запах земляники**: метрах в десяти (свидетельство вашего звериного обоняния) за кочкой поляна ― вот такие ягоды, как лаком облитые, ослепительные. [Анатолий Найман, Галина Наринская. Процесс еды и беседы. 100 кулинарных и интеллектуальных рецептов // «Октябрь», 2003](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CE%F1%F2%F0%FB%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&docid=46366)

Однако, в большинстве случаев (не буду приводить [цитаты](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CE%F1%F2%F0%FB%E9%20%E7%E0%EF%E0%F5&p=0)) острым называют запах ассоциирующийся с кислым или солёным вкусом – запах пота, дыма, сгоревшего пороха, летучих веществ – лаков, красок, аммиака, бензина, лекарств.

И ещё раз хотел бы сказать, всё, связанное с запахами, глубоко субъективно. Возможно, у дегустаторов есть специальная терминология для описания запахов, но в обычной речи и в художественной литературе один и тот же запах могут описывать совершенно разными прилагательными, часто диаметрально противоположными.